# CSS Gradients in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, nativescript

So my question relates with how would I add CSS gradients to NativeScript?

I currently have an .xml file and a .js file for the mock visualization. All I can show is one standard color on my emulator now. Is there a way I could add gradients in the .css file itself or any other way where its possible to add gradients instead of hardcoding it into the app itself as the app I am working on would require different gradients on different pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** : NativeScript 4.x and above is now supporting linear-gradient.
An example can be seen in [this documentation article](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/styling)

Welcome to StackOverflow and NativeScript!
Curr,ently CSS-gradients are future feature for {N}.
However, you can implement them using the native code for Android and iOS.

Good linear gradient sample implementations for both platforms are shown in this discussion : 
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/539

Comment: Can u help me on this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262183/assertion-failure-and-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-nativescript