# Assertion failure and NSInternalInconsistencyException in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Can anyone help me on this? I am trying to run my `NativeScript + Angular` app in my iPhone.

**Terminal Creation**

> Created `tns create mysample --ng` app, added iOS platform, successfully built with warnings and run time error arising when I tried to run in Xcode.

**Playground Creation**

> Downloaded `NativeScript + Angular` app from `NativeScriptPlayground`, added iOS platform, successfully built with warnings and run time error arising when I tried to run in Xcode.

**Issue:**

> In both cases, app is successfully installed in my device but when launch screen is launched, then immediately app is getting crashed.

**Build Warnings:** [but, successfully built]

[image]

**Run Time Error:**

[image]

Comment: it looks like either xcode or nativescript isnt installed properly

Comment: app is getting installed, then, tns doctor also working fine,

Comment: Are you making any changes to the app; or just `tns create mysample --ng` then `tns platform add ios` then `tns run ios`?     Does it fail on a simulator?

Comment: **tns create mysample --ng** , **tns platform add ios**, then, made change **enableProdMode();** in main.ts and main.js, then, **tns build ios**, once built successfully, opened my **Xcode.project**, try to run in my device, app is getting installed and getting crashed. @Nathanael

Comment: Can u guide me on this?? @Nathanael

Comment: This is not a good area for tech support; I would recommend you open an issue on the NativeScript github issue tracker; or on the NativeScript forums.   Need a lot more info like device, does it work on emulators, what versions of runtime, cli, etc.

Comment: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/unable-to-run-ns-angular-app-in-my-ios-device/6858?u=gkrz I have posted my question in NativeScript forum. Possible, help me on this.